# I need to print columns from two different files with the different numbers of rows into one file

Tags: sed, gawk

File1.txt

```
123 321 231
234 432 342
345 543 453
```

file2.txt

```
abc bca cba
def efd fed
ghi hig ihg
jkl klj lkj
mno nom onm
pqr qrp rqp
```

I want output file like
Outfile.txt

```
123 321 231 abc bca cba
234 432 342 def efd fed
345 543 453 ghi hig ihg
jkl klj lkj
mno nom onm
pqr qrp rqp
```

Answer (score 1):

Most simply:

```
sed 's/$/ /' file1 | paste -d '' - file2
```

This appends spaces to the end of lines in `file1` and pastes the output of that together with `file2` without a delimiter.

Alternatively, if you know that `file2` is longer than `file1`,

```
awk 'NR == FNR { line1[NR] = $0 " "; next } { print line1[FNR] $0 }' file1 file2
```

or if you don't know it,

```
awk 'NR == FNR { n = NR; line1[n] = $0 " "; next } { print line1[FNR] $0 } END { for(i = FNR + 1; i <= n; ++i) print line1[i]; }' file1 file2
```

also works.